# setRefClass pass by value, pass by reference

Tags: r, reference-class

I suspect i am not understanding all the aspects of `setRefClass` in R. Lets say I have an instance of a `setRefClass` initialized. I want to create the variable `X` so that this variable is equal to a copy of the instance or refers to the instance of `setRefClass`.
Is there a difference between:

```
x = InstanceOfsetRefClass
```

and

```
x <<- InstanceOfsetRefClass
```

I don't fully understand and it seems I have strange behavior in my code.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not probably for this question, but in general, I think reading [**this wiki**](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/R5) should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is anything to do with reference classes, rather it's about scope. Consider the following example. We start by removing all variables from our workspace and create a definition for `A`:

```
rm(list=ls())
A = setRefClass("A", fields=list(x="numeric"))
```

Next we create and call the function `f`:

```
f = function() {
  x1 = 1
  a1 = A$new(x=10)
  x2 <<- 2
  a2 <<- A$new(x=10)
}
f()
```

The key difference between `<<-` and `=` is

> The operators '<<-' and '->>' are normally only used in functions, and
>   cause a search to made through parent environments for an existing
>   definition of the variable being assigned.  If such a variable is
>   found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined,
>   otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment.
>
> From the help page: ?"<<-"

So variables created using `=` aren't found in the global enviroment

```
R> x1
Error: object 'x1' not found
R> a1
Error: object 'a1' not found
```

but the other variables are:

```
R> x2
[1] 2
R> a2
Reference class object of class "A"
Field "x":
[1] 10
```

Comment: ok so i think i am better off using = inside a function not to mess with the GlobalEnv and create conflict in case to variables would have the same name?

Comment: @user1176316 Yes *but* within the reference object you'd use `<<-` to up date the variables in the fields. See the example at the bottom of `?setRefClass`

Comment: I agree. I sometimes encounter "local assignment to field name will not change the field" trying to use create a variable inside a method in the setRefClass. I am not sure what it means.

Comment: You would get this error if you used `=` on a variable in a field.

Comment: One last question. If you want to use a variable inside a methods of a setRefClass, you do it the standard way ? " x = 1 "?

Comment: Yes, unless you want it to be persistent.